# Disable a div with a transparent div

Tags: html, disabled-input, css

I'm trying to disable some portions of my html pages.
I read that you can use a transparent div with absolute position on top of your page to prevent clicking on elements beyond it, but is there a way to accomplish this only on a portion of a page (let's assume this portion is all contained in a div) without the use of absolute position?

Comment: Can you post an example of the mark-up you're working with, and clearly identify which portions of that page should be 'disabled'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `position: relative` on the div you want to disable, then add the transparent blocking div as a child of this div with `position: absolute` and `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` equal to 0.

If you are unable to put `position: relative` on the div you want to disable then it will be a bit more difficult as you need to compute it's dimensions and offset and then position the transparent mask as a child of the body and at the exact same position as the element you need to disable. JS frameworks (as jQuery) usually provide you with ways to determine a box's [offset relative to the document](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

Answer (score 0):

Make a little 1px x 1px transparent image and save it as a .png file.
In the CSS for your DIV, use this code

```
background:transparent url('/images/transparent-bg.png') repeat center top;
```

Remember to change the file path to your transperant image.

I think this solution works in all browsers, maybe except for IE 6, but I haven't tested it.